# How to get the execution time for a task using celery?

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I want to fetch the execution time for any task, assuming I have task_id with me. Is there a way to get the execution time?  I know the time will be logged by celery, but I don't want to parse the log file. On similar lines, is there a way to get the waiting time as well for a task, in other words, from the time the task has been scheduled to a worker node to the time when it starts to execute. Basically I want to capture the entire lifetime of any task.

Comment: My initial thoughts. I have a custom scheduler which schedules the incoming tasks to various worker nodes. So, when the task is scheduled, I make an entry in result backend(redis) with task id. When the task is completed, the result will be logged in redis with task id prefixed with "celery-meta-blah-blah". I could find the differnce between these two entry timestamps. But this would involve the overhead caused due to msg transmission. So, figuring out for other ways.

Comment: I was able to achieve this using events.

Comment: Could you please show some code on how you achieve this?

Comment: This is not an efficient solution though. Keep listening for task_start and task_succeeded events. Whenever you see task_start event, log into some DB with timestamp. And when you get to see task_succeeded for the same add another entry to DB with current timestamp. The difference between two gives you the total time the task has taken.